# Specifying an object should be empty if another object has properties in JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

I have data that comes back from GraphQL, I'd like to verify that data with JSON schema before manipulating it.

There might be a better way of doing this in graphQL than I currently am, but the data that comes back can be of two types with the same properties:

e.g. a simplified version of the data

```
obj: {
  audio: {
    artists: []
  },
  video: {}
}
```

or

```
obj: {
  audio: {},
  video: {
    artists: []
  }
}
```

So validity would be:

- an object with both a `audio` and `video` property
- an object with `audio` as an object with a property `artists` and an empty property `video` object
- an object with `video` as an object with a property `artists` and an empty property `audio` object
- neither `audio` or `video` should be empty together
- neither `audio` or `video` should have properties together

I've built a simplified schema that looks like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "file://schemas/simple.schema.json",
  "title": "simplified data",
  "description": "simple",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "audio": {
      "type": "object"
    },
    "video": {
      "type": "object"
    }
  },
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "audio": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "artists": {
            "type": "array"
          }
        }
      },
      "video": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {}
      }
    },
    {
      "audio": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {}
      },
      "video": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "artists": {
            "type": "array"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

but AJV doesn't seem to validate the data correctly when run against:

```
{
  "audio": {
    "artists": []
  },
  "video": {}
}
```

What might have I got wrong with my schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After an initial attempt, Jason pointed out a simpler solution...

Using `oneOf`, you can specify that only one of the objects may have at least one property.

You can test this here: https://jsonschema.dev/s/SSRaL

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "file://schemas/simple.schema.json",
  "properties": {
    "audio": {
      "type": [
        "object"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "artists": {
          "$comment": "whatever validation you want"
        }
      }
    },
    "video": {
      "type": [
        "object"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "artists": {
          "$comment": "whatever validation you want"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "video": {
          "minProperties": 1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "audio": {
          "minProperties": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The `if`/`then`s aren't necessary. The `oneOf` is enough. Also `"not": { "additionalProperties": false }` can be simplified as `"minProperties": 1`.

Comment: Yeah actually you're right. I added the `oneOf` after the other parts of the schema. I'll update the answer to reflect. Thanks.